# Redirecting stdout and stderr in both C and C++ on Windows

Tags: c++, windows

We're moving from Visual Studio 2013 to VS 2019, and it's no longer possible to assign to "_file" in the code below. I've been looking at other questions about this, and it's just not clear to me what to do. I see references to using freopen, which we use on Linux, but I'm not sure how that fits into this mechanism where we're piping to a child process, which then uses our custom print function that sends the output to the various places it's supposed to go. It's also not clear in those answers that it works on Windows. Links to posts where it talks about this tend to be broken, so some of the promising introductory answers were dead ends.

Ideally, the solution will work on both VS 2013 and VS 2019, but if not, I can conditionally compile it to handle that.

```
DWORD WINAPI io_thread (LPVOID *param);

void captureStdStreams (const char *outfile)
    {
    static HANDLE readHandle;
    static HANDLE writeHandle;

    FILE *xxx = stderr;

    if (CreatePipe (&readHandle, &writeHandle, 0, 0))
        {
        SetStdHandle (STD_ERROR_HANDLE, writeHandle);
        SetStdHandle (STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE, writeHandle);
        int fd = _open_osfhandle ((intptr_t) writeHandle, O_WRONLY | O_TEXT);
        dup2 (fd, 2);
        stderr->_file = fd;
        dup2 (fd, 1);
        stdout->_file = fd;
        }

    HANDLE th = CreateThread (0, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) io_thread, &readHandle, 0, 0);
    CloseHandle (th);
    }

DWORD WINAPI io_thread (LPVOID *param)
    {
    HANDLE readHandle = *(HANDLE *) param;

    // Line buffer and pointer

    static char iobuf[256];
    static unsigned int bp = 0;

    for (;;)
        {
        DWORD nread;

        if (ReadFile (readHandle, &iobuf[bp], 1, &nread, 0))
            {
            if (bp == sizeof (iobuf) - 1 || iobuf[bp] == '\n')
                {
                productspecific::print ("%.*s", bp + 1, iobuf);
                bp = 0;
                }
            else
                {
                bp += 1;
                }
            }
        }

    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: why on earth would you do that? Let the shell handle redirection. And in case you want to write to file just open a file normally

Comment: I must do this.